# how to determine last words of each string?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop, c-strings, strtok

I have this assignment:

> Enter a sequence of sentences from the keyboard into the string array (the end of entering - empty string). Determine the last word of each of these sentences.

The problem is that my program outputs the last word of the last sentence, and I need the last word of each sentence to be output.

Program I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char str[10][100];
   int i;

   printf("Enter a sequence of sentences:\n");

   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       if (*gets(str) == '\0')
          break;
   }

   printf("The last word of each of these sentences is:\n");
 
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       char *word;
       word = strtok(str[i], ".");
       while (word != NULL) {
           char *last_word = word;
           word = strtok(NULL, ".");
       }
       printf("%s\n", last_word);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What problem would you like us to help you with? Does the program do something unexpected (what is it? what was your expectation?) for some specific input (...?). Or do you have some other question? Please [edit] your post to include it.

Comment: First, never use `gets`.  But, if for some reason you choose to use `gets` (which you should not do), the argument it takes should be a `char *`.  In your code, `str` is *not* a `char *`, so passing it as the argument to `gets` is invalid.  Your compiler should warn you of this error.  (It should also tell you that you should not be using `gets` at all!)

Comment: Learn about `strchr` or `strrchr` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delimiter in this call

```
word = strtok(str[i], ".");
```

does not make sense.

It seems you mean

```
word = strtok(str[i], " \t.");
```

provided that a sentence can be ended only with a dot and words are separated by spaces or tab characters.

Another problem is that the variable `last_word` must be declared before the while loop.

For example

```
   char *last_word = NULL;
   char *word;
   word = strtok(str[i], " \t.");
   while (word != NULL) {
       last_word = word;
       word = strtok(NULL, " \t.");
   }
```

And it is better to use for loop instead of the while loop

```
   char *last_word = NULL;

   for ( char *word = strtok(str[i], " \t." );
         word != NULL;
         word = strtok(NULL, " \t.") ) 
   {
       last_word = word;
   }
```

Pay attention to that the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use standard C function `fgets`.

And the condition in the second for loop

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    char *word;
    //...
```

is incorrect because the user can enter less than `10` sentences.

Comment: If suggesting `fgets()`, then useful to add `'\n'` to the end-of-word token set: `" \t."`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think in a next post he will ask how to remove the new line character and he will get an answer.:)

Answer (score 1):

Without repeating the commentary of the accepted answer provided by @Vlad (kudos!), here is an alternative offering (with comments)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void ) {
    // A single large buffer allowing very long lines to be entered.
    char buf[ 10 * 100 ], *p = buf;
    size_t left = sizeof buf;
    int i = 0;

    // up to 10 'lines' of input, breaking on an empty line, too
    while( i++ < 10 && fgets( p, left, stdin ) && p[0] != '\n' ) {

        // typical invocation of strtok() to isolate "words"
        // and a "wasteful" copy of each word to the current start of the buffer
        for( char *tkn = p; ( tkn = strtok( tkn, " .\n" ) ) != NULL; tkn = NULL )
            strcpy( p, tkn );

        // having copied the last "word", append '\n' and advance the pointer
        size_t len =  strlen( p );
        p += len;
        strcpy( p++, "\n" );
        left -= len + 1; // eroding the available size of the buffer
    }

    printf( "%s", buf ); // a single output of "word1\nword2\nword3\n..."

    return 0;
}
```

NB: `strcpy()` of overlapping buffers is fraught with hazards. This works in this case, but the practise and its effects must be very well considered before using this technique.